# a.b < 0, why does this not throw an error when a.b === undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, comparison, throw, operands

A typo ended up as

```
a.b > 0
```

with `a.b` undefined. According to MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Greater_than_operator) the comparison calls `.valueOf()` on the operands. So it should be

```
a.b.valueOf() > 0
```

but that actually throws an error which does not seem to happen. Instead this seems to be evaluated:

```
undefined > 0
```

Am I misunderstanding something?

In my case this led to a silent error in the Node.js code. I certainly wanted that an error was thrown instead.

Can I handle this without explicitly checking the operands?

---

EDIT: freeCodeCamp seems to describe this more correct than MDN:

https://guide.freecodecamp.org/javascript/comparison-operators/

But I still wonder about the most easy way to handle this without being trapped by simple typos.

Comment: It could throw an error if a is undefined and you are trying to access a.b, is a defined at the moment you are trying to access a.b?

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Yes, as I said `a.b` is `undefined` (which means that `a !== undefined`.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky Hm, I did not write that clearly in the question. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: "*the comparison calls `.valueOf()` on the operands*" - only if the operand is an object. It doesn't do that on primitive values

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, yes I understand that now, but MDN just says "Each of these operators will call the valueOf() function on each operand before a comparison is made". But still I wonder how people handle this. A typo happens easily.

Comment: @Leo Oh, wow. I've fixed MDN now.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks. That looks good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-relational-operators): what it does [is](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-relational-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation):

> 5. Let r be the result of performing Abstract Relational Comparison lval < rval.

which [does](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-relational-comparison), which tries to coerce each side to a primitive first:

> a. Let px be ? ToPrimitive(x, hint Number).
>
> b. Let py be ? ToPrimitive(y, hint Number).

`undefined` is already a primitive - nothing throws. Then, it does:

> Let nx be ? ToNumeric(px).
>
> Let ny be ? ToNumeric(py).

Casting `undefined` to a Number doesn't throw either, but it returns `NaN`:

```js
console.log(Number(undefined));
```

So then we get to

> If Type(nx) is the same as Type(ny), return Type(nx)::lessThan(nx, ny).

where `nx` is `NaN` and `ny` is 0. `lessThan` returns `undefined` when `nx` is `NaN`, described [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-numeric-types-number-lessThan):

> 1. If x is NaN, return undefined.

And then, coming back to the step after the `5.` at the very beginning of the answer:

> 7. If r is undefined, return false. Otherwise, return r.

The result is `undefined`, so `false` is returned (without an error being thrown).

---

> So it should be
>
> ```
>   a.b.valueOf() > 0
> ```

Only an *object* will have `valueOf` called on it in the process of `<` evaluation (in the `a. Let px be ? ToPrimitive(x, hint Number).` above). `undefined` is not an object - it's already a primitive, so no additional conversion happens at that step.

> I certainly wanted that an error was thrown instead.
>
> Can I handle this without explicitly checking the operands?

Not really, but that shouldn't be hard to do at all - just check that `a.b` is a Number first if you aren't sure. `if (typeof a.b === 'number')`. Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Thanks, that is a good explanation. And it means MDN simplifies it too much (in the link I gave). I am however also looking for a safe way to handle this.

Comment: Thanks, so I have to explicitly check the operands.